# MongoDB version 4^ -- get list of all databases in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Title pretty much says it all, I've seen other answers on here, and even in the documentation, to use db.admin().listDatabases, but what I couldn't figure out was it what "db" is, since in the newer versions mongoclient only returns the client object, which you must call client.db("dbname") to get the specific db object, but how can I get a list of all of the database names??!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the `.listCollections()` method on the db object

```
const _db = await  mongo.getDb(MONGODB_URI); // to get the db object here
const collections = await _db.listCollections({}).toArray();
```

**Update2**

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
  // Use the admin database for the operation
  const adminDb = client.db('local').admin();
  // List all the available databases
  adminDb.listDatabases(function(err, dbs) {
    console.log(dbs.databases);
    client.close();
  });
});
```

or using async await style

```
const connection = await MongoClient.connect(url,
      { useNewUrlParser: true });

    var dbs = await connection.db('test').admin().listDatabases();
```

Comment: I'm looking to list all databases in a particular mongo client, not all collections in a database

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I updated the answer, but haven't tested it myself

Comment: Interesting so you have to use the Db class? Is there a way to do it with the MongoClient connection object used like MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client)=>console.log(client.db.admin().listDatabases()).  ?

Comment: Also what is the variable databaseName?

Comment: I have updated the answer again. The variable seems to be not important when listing all the database name.

Comment: I just reread your question again. It seems like getting a list of databases in 4.x is the same as 2.x?